# Unix search and remove variable (contains slash) from a file

Tags: sed, replace

I have a requirement to search for a variable "nt" ( contains a slash). From a file text1 and remove all lines containing it

```
$ echo $nt
/u01/app/us1fa01_0/

$ cat text1
/u01/app/fa01/
/u01/app/us1fa01_0/
/u01/app/us1fa01_ps6/
```

Expected output-

```
$ cat text1
/u01/app/fa01/
/u01/app/us1fa01_ps6/
```

I tried the following commands:

1. `sed "/$nt/d" text1`

   ```
   sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `u'
   ```
2. `sed "|$nt|d" text1`

   ```
   sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `|'
   ```
3. `sed '\|"$nt"|d' text1`

   ```
   /u01/app/fa01/
   /u01/app/us1fa01_0/
   /u01/app/us1fa01_ps6/
   ```

None of the above codes seem to work. Looking for a way out

Comment: Just edited the value of -nt. It should be 
$echo $nt  
/u01/app/us1fa01_0/

Comment: In the last version (3), the single quotation marks will inhibit parameter expansion for `$nt`. So you will search for `$nt` there, not for its expansion.

Comment: are you not missing the `s` in sed: `sed "s/$nt/d" text1`?

Comment: No luck 
$sed "s/$nt/d" text1
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ***grep***:

```
grep -Fv -f <(echo "$nt") text1
```

- `-F` - interpret the pattern as a list of fixed strings
- `-v` - invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines
- `-f` - obtain patterns from file, one per line

The output:

```
/u01/app/fa01/
/u01/app/us1fa01_ps6/
```

Comment: @nehadhawan, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed "\#$nt#d" text1 
/u01/app/fa01/
/u01/app/us1fa01_ps6/
```

`sed` allows you to use an arbitrary pattern delimiter if you quote it with `\`.

This will *fail* if `$nt` contains any `#` characters.  In this case, use another delimiter.

Note that this will delete line that contains the pattern anywhere on the line.

To force the pattern to match across the whole line, use

```
$ sed "\#^$nt\$#d" text1
```

Here, we need to quote the end-of-line anchor `$` from the shell with `\$`.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed (not sure about other sed implementations), you can use `\%pattern%`, where `%` is an arbitrary character.

So the following should work:

```
sed "\%$nt%d" text1
```

Comment: That made sense too. Tks